# File permissions with s3fs and ubuntu

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse

I followed this guide to set up an amazon s3 upload procedure for my ember-js application with grunt-s3:
http://www.octolabs.com/blogs/octoblog/2014/05/24/deploying-ember-cli-to-amazon-s3-with-grunt/

I noticed that when mounting the s3 filesystem in my ubuntu server, all the files were with permission mode 000.

I want to have the files with permission 644. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the options section of my grunt.js file I added "x-amz-meta-mode": "33188"

```
options: {
    key: '<%= aws.AWSAccessKeyId %>',
    secret: '<%= aws.AWSSecretKey %>',
    bucket: '<%= aws.bucket %>',
    access: 'public-read',
    headers: {
      // Two Year cache policy (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 730)
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=630720000, public",
      "x-amz-meta-mode": "33188",
      "Expires": new Date(Date.now() + 63072000000).toUTCString()
    }
```